# org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not found: NT

Tags: jena

I am writing a Java program that contains the following line:

```
this.model = readOntology(pathToTripleFile, "NT");
```

I am using dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
   <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
   <version>3.13.1</version>
   <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

It runs fine on MacOS but when I package it (with dependencies) and run it on Linux I get the following error:

```
org.apache.jena.shared.NoReaderForLangException: Reader not found: NT
```

Comment: A possibility is that the repackimg did not include the servlce loader files: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jena has an initialization sequence that is used to setup components available at runtime. (see [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/system-initialization.html))

When making a combined jar ("uber-jar", "fat-jar", "jar with dependencies") from Jena dependencies and application code, the contents of the Jena files must be combined and be present in the combined jar as a java resource of the same name. (see [here](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/jena-repack.html))

This can be achieved with the `maven shade` plugin (note that I am not using the `maven-assembly-plugin` anymore).

With this plugin configuration, the application runs on the server:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheLicenseResourceTransformer" />
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ApacheNoticeResourceTransformer">
                <addHeader>false</addHeader>
            </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <!-- Some jars are signed but shading breaks that.
                         Don't include signing files.
                    -->
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <!--<phase /><!- - Switch off -->
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I used the configuration from the [fuseki project](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-server/pom.xml).

Thank you @AndyS for pointing me into this direction!